# Use Facebook Messenger bot to interact with Shared Days

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have just started looking into Facebook Messenger's bots and am thinking of making one.

Recently, Facebook Messenger has introduced the idea of *Shared Days*, which are basically Snapchat-like stories that people can post to and share for their friends to see.

Does Facebook's APIs allow one to use a bot to create stories (post pictures to shared days)?

I am looking at the APIs and cannot find anyway to do this. I want to create a bot that can post stories on Facebook Messenger's *Shared Days*. I want the bot to post stories periodically on its own story that only its subscribers can see, if that's possible.

Any reference to some documentation, and perhaps a simple toy example would be helpful.

Comment: No there is no API for that

Comment: @WizKid so, in other words, there is no way of accomplishing what I want?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Currently, you cannot post to a user's or page's "My Day" using the Send API or any other apis.**

That doesn't cut you off entirely from using them in your bot, however. Facebook is making it easier to share content from bots to your friends or my day with each iteration of messenger.

When your bot puts an image file into chat as an upload, your user can click the share arrow next to the image, or at the bottom left when fullscreened, and share it to their day, their friends, group chats, etc.

[image: share dialog]

IMO, This is a very powerful viral tool that no one is using yet.

Comment: I was aware of this, unfortunately its not what I was trying to achieve but seeing as this is the closest answer I'll get I'll accept it